# Migrate Rails and connect back to existing database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

It's been a few years since I've actively worked in Rails so I'm pretty rusty.  I need to migrate a Rails app (website) from an old machine to a new one.  I also need to move the database which is housed on another machine and partly used for other things.

I can physically transfer the code between machines, that's easy.  If memory serves me, I need to dump the database, but omit something, but I can't remember what.  From there, I'm a bit hazy.  If it helps (or hinders) its an old Rails 4 app that I'm looking reviving.

Comment: Hm, I don't think you omit anything. You can dump the db, schema and data, restore it on a new db server and point your new rails app server to this db. If your app uses other dependencies (like redis), you might want to move them too.

Comment: Turned out it was triggers in the DB that I shouldn't include, so not Rails related.  I've got as much as I can working, but when I do "rails s" it tells me there are migrations pending, which I know wasn't the case when I last worked on the code.